# Contribution margin percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I have made a formula to calculate contribution margin of a product, the thing is that the percentage is limited to 100%.

If we buy a product for 0.2€ and sell it for 99€, basically we earn more then 100% of the value.

```
$("#tb_calculator").change(function(){
$this = $(this);
var price_in = $this.find(".tb_price_in").val().replace(',', '.');
var price_out = $this.find(".tb_price_out").val().replace(',', '.');
var quantity = $this.find(".tb_quantity").val().replace(',', '.');

//var percentage = (price_out / price_in - 1)*100;
var percentage = (price_in / price_out);
var tb_value = (price_out*quantity - price_in*quantity);

//console.log(percentage);
var final_percentage = Math.round(((1-percentage)*100));
if (final_percentage === Infinity || final_percentage === "" || isNaN(final_percentage) || final_percentage < 0 || percentage < 0) {
  var final_percentage = 0;
}
if (tb_value === Infinity || tb_value === "" || isNaN(tb_value)) {
  var tb_value = 0;
}

function tofixed(val)
{
   return parseFloat(val.toFixed(2));
}

$(".tb_count").val(tofixed(tb_value)+"kr - ("+final_percentage+"%)");
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xccvcxup/)

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: If you want to get review for your code you have to go [CR](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @hindmost I daresay that the code is not finished, since there is an obvious problem with it's functionality. As such it is **off-topic** for Code Review. For more information, see: [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow Users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: If the formula you're after is that if you buy something at $2 and sell it at $8, then you have 300% profit, you can use: (sales price - buy price) / buy price * 100.  For your $0.2 sold for $99, this would mean a 49400% profit. If that's not what you're calculating (im not an economics mayor), just ignore this. :)